# renaming $lvl1.lvl2.lvl3 to $lvl1['lvl2']['lvl3']

Tags: php, regex

I've created a textarea that allows users to echo variables:

```
Hello {$name}!
```

...and arrays too:

```
Hello {$person.name}
```

Using the folllowing line to PREG_REPLACE the string so it can be eval()'ed by PHP:

```
$input = preg_replace( $patter , $replacement , $input);
```

I got it to work with shallow variables:

`'/{\$([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)}/'` becomes `<?php echo $$1; ?>`

...and with 1- 2- or 3-level deep arrays:

`'/{\$([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\.([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\.([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\.([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)}/'`

becomes `<?php echo $$1['$2']['$3']['$4']; ?>`

But what I really want is unlimited levels... something like....

`'/{\$([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)<\.([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)>}/'` becomes `<?php echo $$1<['$*']>; ?>`

Sorry if this is giving you a headache - it sure is giving me!

Comment: Yuck, eval. Couldnt you just search for {$name} and use preg_replace to replace it to the correct variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using mustache instead:

mustache.github.com

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but we've decided not to use a template engine :)

Comment: why not?  It seems like you're trying to write a template engine yourself, and as far as I can tell the functionality you're looking for is exactly what mustache provides... even almost the same template syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Probably should use something existing, like [mustache](http://mustache.github.com) as Brian suggested.

But this is a more reasonable way to do the replacement than eval. All you need to do is adjust whatever dot notation resolving function you prefer.

```
<?php
$input = 'Hello {$name}!  Hello {$person.name}! Hello {$person.unknown}!';

$data = array(
    'name' => 'fred',
    'person' => array(
        'name'=>'freddie'
    )
);

// extract tokens
preg_match_all('/{\$([A-Z.]*)}/i', $input, $tokens);

// declare non-recursive dot notation resolver
function resolve_token($data, $token){
    $token = str_replace(array('{','}','$'), '', $token);
    $steps = explode('.', $token);
    foreach($steps as $step){
        if( !isset($data[$step]) ) return false;
        $data = $data[$step];
    }
    return $data;
}

// get token list
$list = array();
foreach($tokens[0] as $token){
    $list[$token] = resolve_token($data, $token);
    // if you want to leave unresolved tokens in place
    // remove from $list, or never add to $list
}
$output =  str_replace( array_keys($list), array_values($list), $input);

echo "original: {$input}\n";
echo "output: {$output}\n";
```